# Editing templates from MaterialDesignInXaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate, material-design-in-xaml

I am attempting to use the materialDesignInXaml StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextBox. I have an issue where say, I want an not selected textBox to be Blue, and when i select the textbox, it appears to turn green.

From comment below, i was able to get the selected textbox border brush to turn green using,    materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.UnderlineBrush.  However, i do not know how to control the borderbrush color when it is unselected to turn to blue.  Default is black but I am unable to figure out where this color is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different brushes involved. One is used for the underline color on hovering and the other is used in case the value is proved invalid through validation. The normal underline can be changed through the `TextFieldAssist.UnderlineBrush` attached property on the `TextBox`.

```
<TextBox materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.UnderlineBrush="Green">
```

The validation brush called `MaterialDesignValidationErrorBrush` (red by default) is referenced in the control template for `TextBox` using a `DynamicResource`, so you can override it in the local resources (or application if you want) without needing to copy or change the control template.

```
<TextBox>
   <TextBox.Resources>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MaterialDesignValidationErrorBrush" Color="Green"/>
   </TextBox.Resources>
   <!-- ...other markup. -->
</TextBox>
```

Comment: thank you, <TextBox materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.UnderlineBrush="Green">
 allowed me to change to green when active,  what property would it be to change the color of the border when not selected to be say "yellow" instead of black.

Comment: @leon Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70242571/6181599) :-) .

Comment: thank you!  could you help me understand the x:Key="MaterialDesignTextAreaBorder", is this key already pre-defined key in MaterialDesigninXaml?  I tried to control-f to find the key definition but do not see it.

Comment: @leon Yes, it is defined in [`MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml`](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/1f2aa7e79d3e738027580759f5d36a031331bc07/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml#L38) and [`MaterialDesignTheme.Dark.xaml`](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/1f2aa7e79d3e738027580759f5d36a031331bc07/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Dark.xaml#L38).