# Changing outlined TextBox default border brush

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, material-design-in-xaml

Currently, when `TextBox` is not selected, the `BorderBrush` is black. However, when `TextBox` is selected, the `BorderBrush` becomes green. How would I go about setting the `BorderBrush` to be say blue by default when not selected instead of black?

```
<TextBox 
    Margin="0,15,0,0"
    Foreground="#FFFFFF"
    FontSize="20"
    materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.UnderlineBrush="Green"
    materialDesign:HintAssist.Background="Transparent"
    Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextBox}"
    materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Username"
    materialDesign:HintAssist.Foreground="Green"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the BorderBrush

```
<TextBox BorderBrush="Blue" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the following brushes:

- `MaterialDesignTextAreaBorder` - For the border in enabled state.
- `MaterialDesignTextAreaInactiveBorder` - For the border in disabled state (`IsEnabled="False"`).

```
<TextBox 
   Margin="0,15,0,0"
   Foreground="#FFFFFF"
   FontSize="20"
   materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.UnderlineBrush="Green"
   materialDesign:HintAssist.Background="Transparent"
   Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextBox}"
   materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Username"
   materialDesign:HintAssist.Foreground="Green">
   <TextBox.Resources>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MaterialDesignTextAreaBorder" Color="Blue"/>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MaterialDesignTextAreaInactiveBorder" Color="LightBlue"/>
   </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>
```